# Character n-gram vs word features in NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-selection

I'm trying to predict if reviews on yelp are positive or negative by performing linear regression using SGD.
I tried two different feature extractors.
The first was the character n-gram and the second was separating words by space.
 However, I tried different n values for the character n-gram, and found that the n value that gave me the best test error.
I noticed that this test error (0.27 in my test data) was nearly identical to the test error from extracting the words separated by space.
Is there a reason behind this coincidence?
Shouldn't the character n-gram have a lower test error since it extracted more features than the word features?

Character n-gram: ex. n=7
"Good restaurant" => "Goodres" "oodrest" "odresta" "drestau" "restaur" "estaura" "stauran" "taurant"

Word features:
"Good restaurant" => "Good" "restaurant"

Comment: Your question is about feature-selection and feature-engineering for NLP. As such it belongs on sister site [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: character n-gram is not suitable for NLP. In NLP world, I think n-gram meaning "word" n-gram. We have a Solr using CJK tokenizer and its term is totally useless for NLP or text mining, IMHO. I'm looking for another dictionary-based tokenizer instead for our text mining project in 2018. I also consider use R studio and RWordseg to do text mining instead of using Solr with something else.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the n-gram method simply produced a lot of redundant, overlapping features which do not contribute to the precision.